# Swift - How to get latitude and longitude value outside function LocationManager()

Tags: swift, firebase, core-location, locationmanager

i am working with Firebase Db, and i want to save lat,long value of device on Firebase. I had two value from locationManager()

This is my function locationManager()

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       let lastLocation: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]
       let lat = String(format: "%.6f", lastLocation.coordinate.latitude)
       let long = String(format: "%.6f", lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }
```

Next, i try TO save lat,long on Firebase:

```
 ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.setValue(lat)
```

> Error: "Use of Unresolved Identifier".

How to get latitude and longitude value outside function LocationManager().

Answer (score 3):

You can declare `CLLocationManagerDelegate` right where of your class definition.

```
class YourClass {
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
}
```

And in your location delegate method you assign the current value

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    currentCoordinate = manager.location.coordinate
}
```